# Cash Flow Timeline Graph

Tags: excel, charts, powerbi, data-visualization

I have an excel sheet with 6 columns:

3 different cash flows (30%,60% and 10% of the project value)
3 columns with their respective dates
As an example, suppose total contract value is 100 USD, I receive USD 30 on 15.02.2019, USD 60 on 15.03.2020 and USD 10 on 15.03.2021. This is one row and 6 columns.

I want to present this information in 1 single chart/visualization. There are about 200 rows and the dates are not in a particular order, it's random.
When I try to combine the data X axis (dates) and all the 3 Cash flows (on Y axis), it doesn't make sense, it gets chaotic and moreover the dates only come up for the 30% Cash flow.

I want X axis with all the dates and on Y axis to have the cash flows with 3 legends (30%,60% and 10%) on their respective dates.So in nutshell , as an example the graph can show  that on 1st January 2019 I had a total cash flow of 10 USD from 30% Cash flow, 5 from 60% and 2 from 10 %.I am not an advanced user in Excel so would appreciate your help! If I need to format my data to some particular way-I can do that as well.What graph should I use?

I am ready to use Power BI or any other free solution as well-if its easy there!

PS-I tried doing a combo chart and then making changes to data as well(but, still it doesn't work!) under Design>Select Data-tried everything!

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform aka. normalize your data first.

What you have is 6 columns:

```
| Cash 30% | Cash 60% | Cash 10% | Date 30% | Date 60% | Date 10% |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
|    30.00 |    60.00 |    10.00 | 20190215 | 20200315 | 20210315 |
```

What you want is the following structure, containing the same information as above, but in a normalized way:

```
| Cash flow pct | Date     | Amount |
| ------------- | -------- | ------ |
|           10% | 20210315 |  10.00 |
|           30% | 20190215 |  30.00 |
|           60% | 20200315 |  60.00 |
```

Once your data is structured this way, visualizing it the way you're describing is straightforward.

Transforming the data is very easy to do using the Power Query editor of Power BI (or Excel for that matter). Post a new question tagged with "powerquery" if you need assistance in how to make a transformation such as this.